# Dynamically concatenating multiple columns in a sequence

Tags: sql

I have a requirement where in I have to concatenate the fields based on their sequence given in another table along with respect to their lengths. 
eg..

**Input:**

> Table A: (below are the fields and their respective values,
>   not all fields will have values)

---

```
KSCHL   - ZIC0 (KEY)   
KOTABNR - 521 (KEY)  
MATNR  
KUNNR-->    1234567890  
LIFNR   
VKORG-->    a234  
PRCTR   
KUNRE-->    4355325363  
LIFRE-->    88390234
```

> Table B: (It contains the same fields as in table A and will have
>   sequence number in which the concatenation should happen. The length
>   field(LEN) will have corresponding field lengths(pipe delimited)
>   should be considered in concatenation)

---

```
KSCHL   - ZIC0 (KEY)   
KOTABNR - 521 (KEY)   
MATNR   
KUNNR-->    1 
LIFNR   
VKORG-->    3  
PRCTR   
KUNRE-->    2  
LIFRE-->    4   
LEN         10|10|4|10
```

**Expected Result**:

---

```
KSCHL - ZIC0 (KEY)   
KOTABNR - 521 (KEY)   
MATNR   
KUNNR   1234567890  
LIFNR   
VKORG   a234  
PRCTR   
KUNRE   4355325363  
LIFRE   0088390234  
Concat_String   12345678904355325363a2340088390234
```

Note: If the field length given in Table B doesn't match with actual size of the fields then, the field should be filled with 2 left spaces while concatenation.. Eg. In above example say `LIFNR` value = `88390234(len=8)` then, after concatenation the value should look like below

```
12345678904355325363a234  88390234
```

I can have any number of fields for concatenation..above example is just for 4...
it should be dynamic enough to handle any number of fields..

Can any one help me on how can I achieve this in SQL?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I want to verify my understanding of your table design.
Are MATNR, KUNNR, LIFNR, and so on, columns found in each table, or are they values within a column (with 1234567890, a234, 4355325363, etc. in a different column)?

Comment: I'm using Sql server...MATNR, KUNNR, LIFNR are fields...Like i said above we have two tables with the same columns names but, one table have actual values and other table has the sequence in which the fields should be concatenated... does this information helpful!!